# SQL Return Characters Right of Last Space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of records in SQL that have a format like this. Note that the spaces are not uniform.

```
WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE NOW            WHAT I WANT IT TO RETURN
================================================================================

PartNumber                        PartNumber           PartNumberStripped
----------------------            --------------------------------------------------
AA BB 11A222                      AA BB 11A222         11A222
AA BB 11B333                      AA BB 11B333         11B333
BBBB 123456                       BBBB 123456          123456
BB BB 2875309                     BB BB 2875309        2875309
CC-BB RANDOMSTRING                CC-BB RANDOMSTRING   RANDOMSTRING
```

How can I return both the 'PartNumber' as well as a part number stripped of all characters to the left of the last space (returning only the characters right of the last space)?

The following is close to what I need, but starts at the left side when looking for the space. I, however, need it to start searching from the right side, effectively.

```
SELECT PartNumber, 
  RIGHT (
    PartNumber
    ,(LEN(PartNumber) - CHARINDEX (' ', PartNumber))
  ) AS PartNumberStripped
FROM tb_Parts
```

This code would return the following, which isn't quite correct as you can see from the "WHAT I WANT IT TO RETURN" section above.

```
PartNumber           PartNumberStripped
---------------------------------------
AA BB 11A222         BB 11A222
AA BB 11B333         BB 11B333
BBBB 123456          123456
BB BB 2875309        BB 2875309
CC-BB RANDOMSTRING   RANDOMSTRING
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess sometimes just typing out your question helps you to wrap your head around it and help with your search queries. I found a working solution using "REVERSE" just a few minutes after posting this question.

```
SELECT 
  PartNumber, 
  RIGHT(PartNumber, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(PartNumber)), 0) - 1, LEN(PartNumber))) AS PartNumberStripped
FROM tb_Parts
```

Source of the solution: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/charindex-in-reverse

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is `parsename()` ... provided you don't have more than 4 spaces

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([PartNumber] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('AA BB 11A222')
,('AA BB 11B333')
,('BBBB 123456')
,('BB BB 2875309')
,('CC-BB RANDOMSTRING')

Select *
      ,NewValue = parsename(replace(PartNumber,' ','.'),1)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
PartNumber          NewValue
AA BB 11A222        11A222
AA BB 11B333        11B333
BBBB 123456         123456
BB BB 2875309       2875309
CC-BB RANDOMSTRING  RANDOMSTRING
```